# WMIC LastBootUptime format problem, total number of days required

Tags: batch-file, cmd, wmic

I am trying to calculate the last time the computer was restarted with CMD.

But I don't want it in Year/month/day format.

Send the total number of days, hours and minutes

Here's what I've been able to do so far:

```
setlocal 
 for /f "skip=1" %%i in ('wmic /node:Computer /USER / os get lastbootuptime') do (
  set string=%%i 
  goto next 
 ) 
 :next 
 echo Son Restart: %string:~6,2%/%string:~4,2%/%string:~0,4%---%string:~8,2%:%string:~10,2%
```

Output: Son Restart: 17/11/2023---02:33

**But what I need: 2 Days - 8 Hours - 43 Minutes**

Note: I should only use CMD, no powershell

Thank you very much for your support in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're happy to use WMIC, then might I offer an alternative method:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set "s="
For /F EOL^=S %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe Path
 Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_System Get SystemUptime  2^>NUL
 ') Do Set /A s=%%G, d=s / 86400, s %%= 86400, h=s / 3600,^
 s %%= 3600, m=s / 60, s=s %% 60 2>NUL
If Defined s (Echo %d% Days - %h% Hours - %m% Minutes
    Pause)
EndLocal
Exit /B
```

Of course you have the option of suffixing  `- %s% Seconds` to the output, should you require that too.

Comment: thank you, it worked great,

But we have a problem,

I am pulling the data from the Remote Computer,

My code gives results in 3 seconds

The code you wrote gives results in 8 seconds.

Is it possible to shorten this period? :(